# Same CPU players are always winning at Mario Kart 8 Deluxe

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

After some time playing at Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, I realized that always (not sometimes or usually, it's always) the two CPU players that obtain the best positions are Toad and Donkey Kong. Although this is not important for playing the game, it's a little frustrating, because I would like to battle for the first place against other players too. I'm tired of Toads and DKs.

I wanted to see if this thing only happens in my game or if it happens in other players games. And if there is any setup where I could change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finallly I discovered the solution [here](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8#Rival_order). The fastest CPU players are not selected at random. They depend on the player you choose. If I choose always Yoshi, then I will always face Toad and DK. So the solution is to choose other players.

Answer (score 3):

I play Mario Kart 8 but not the Deluxe version, but I can say that every time I start a Grand Prix, or any VS Race with multiple tracks, that always two or three CPUs are always better than the rest, and some that are worse.

I think it's just how it's randomized when you start a new Grand Prix or a VS Race. Whenever I start a new Grand Prix race, different characters are in first and second.

I don't know in your case when you say always, whether that is every race in a Grand Prix cup, or in every race, you do no matter what.

Comment: This is true for every Mario Kart I can remember. In a full Grand Prix, the "good" CPU's always stay the same. But it should be somewhat different per each one you do.

Comment: Yes, in other MKs I have played the good players stay during all the grand prix or the versus race, and of course I see it logical. But in my case I'm getting the same good players no matter how many GPs I play.